# transferring a remote file to a remote ftp via php

Tags: php, ftp

I am developing a PHP script.
I would like to transfer a remote ZIP file to a remote FTP (I'm the owner of the FTP account) via PHP.

For example:

I have two hosting accounts: a [Hostgator shared](http://www.hostgator.com/shared.shtml) account and a [Hostgator VPS](http://www.hostgator.com/vps-hosting/) account.
I want to run my PHP script on the VPS hosting.
I'd like my PHP script to upload [this file](http://www.phpbb.com/files/release/phpBB-3.0.9.zip) to the shared hosting account.

Does anyone know a PHP class for this issue?

Comment: Did you look here?  http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: no i did not. i am checking that page right now. thank you very much. A+ help... i must check ftp class out..

Comment: Before ask a question, you'd better try google it first.

Answer (score 2):

From the manual:

```
<?php
$file = 'somefile.txt';
$remote_file = 'readme.txt';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. He wishes to upload a file that is stored on another server.

Comment: I didn't read it that way.  He wants to run the script on B-hostgator to upload the file to A-hostgator.

Comment: Using a script on server B, he wants to upload a file located on phpbb.com to server A.

Comment: Well, hopefully he'll figure out how to use wget or curl to download the file to server B before uploading it to server A via FTP.

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
copy('ftp://user:pass@from.com/file.txt', 'ftp://user:pass@dest.com/file.txt');
```

The PHP server will consume bandwidth upload and download simultaneously.